# JqueryMobile 1.3 ICONS not appearing?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, web-ide, codio

I am creating a mobile application for android on Codio online IDE, and im using jquery mobile. I downloaded the [latest Version: 1.3.0](http://jquerymobile.com/download/)'s .js  &  .css, but [when I run it](https://d.codio.com/hugolpz/Cat-in-migration/App/index.html), all seems to work except JQM icons. **NONE of the JQM icons appears**, while the dark circles should host various white icons.

**How to make JQM icons appears ?**
[image: See the dark circles, there should be white icons !]

---

**Edit: Answer:** search, download, and deploy to the correct place the [Zip File: jquery.mobile-1.3.0.zip](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.zip) (JavaScript, CSS, and images). Available on http://jquerymobile.com/download/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing the icons files. they are referenced in the CSS in your case it's the https://d.codio.com/hugolpz/Cat-in-migration/App/css/images/icons-18-white.png that is missing